# create and plot a cumulative probability density function with custom bin # and sizes of stock price ROC in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, probability-density, ecdf, cumulative-distribution-function

I want to import daily stock market price data into R from any ticker, and examine one historical time segment of it. Then, from this segment, convert these prices into daily ROC/rateofchange % changes. Next, take this ROC series and create a cumulative probability density function which allows me to set any custom number of sorting bins, and any size limit for each bin. example: 22 bins with .3% limit. Next,  plot this  CPDF as either a histogram or a scatterplot. The final step would be to do this for 2 different sections of the same stock and plot them next to each other for visual inspection. I have started a code on stock ticker SPY, but I cannot get it to work.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

# using tidyverse to import a ticker
spy <- tq_get("spy")
spy010422 <- tq_get("spy", get ="stock.prices", from ='2022-01-04', to = '2022-01-24')
str(spy010422)
# getting ROC between prices in the series
spy010422.rtn = ROC(spy010422$close, n = 1, type = c("discrete"), na.pad = TRUE)
str(spy010422.rtn)

# trying to use ggplot and tibble to create an ECDF function
spy010422.rtn %>%
  tibble() %>%
  ggplot() +
  stat_ecdf(aes(.))

# another attempt at running ECDF on the ROC series
spy010422.rtn %>%
  ggplot(spy010422.rtn) +
  stat_ecdf(aes(close))

# trying to set the number of bins and bin size for the ECDF
spy010422.rtn %>%
  mutate(rounded = round(close/.3, 0) *.3,
         bin = min_rank(rounded)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(close, bin)) +
  geom_line()

# next time segment of the ticker spy to compare this to
spy020222 <- tq_get("spy", get ="stock.prices", from ='2022-02-02', to = '2022-02-24')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand what exacly you wanted to plot. Normally a CPDF is just a continuous line, and doesn't have bins to customise. Also "plot this CPDF as either a histogram or a scatterplot" is a weird prhase to me, as one normally plots the histogram/scatterplot of the variable, not of the CPDF of the variable. Given that, I made a function that plots the histogram of the ROC of the ticker, and you can coment if that was what you wanted or not.

The function takes a list of dates in the format `list(c(from1, to1), c(from2, to1), ...)` (you can add as many intervals as you want), and loops for each interval on this list (with the `purrr::map` function). For each interation, it creates the histogram costumizing the `bins` argument. After the loop, the graphs are binded in one figure using the `ggpubr::ggarrange` function (you must run `install.packages("ggpubr")` if you don't have the package installed).

```
library(quantmod)
library(tidyquant)
library(tidyverse)

gg.roc.hist = function(ticker, dates, bins = 30){
  map(dates, function(dates){ #loop for each interval in the 'dates' list
      df = tq_get(ticker, get ="stock.prices", from = dates[1], to = dates[2]) #get the prices
      df$roc = ROC(df$close, n = 1, type = c("discrete"), na.pad = TRUE) #add a column with the ROC
      
      ggplot(df, aes(x = roc)) + 
        geom_histogram(bins = bins) + #create a histogram changing the bins
        labs(title = paste0(dates[1], " to ", dates[2]))}) %>%
    ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = .) #bind the graphs together
}
```

Runnig:

```
gg.roc.hist('spy', list(c('2022-01-04','2022-01-24'), c('2022-02-02', '2022-02-24')), 22)
```

Yields this graph:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for and you are correct, the language I used was not very clear. Thank you for clarifying the terms. This Code is perfect.